# Помогите найти ошибку в задаче. Ошибка - if not recommended: ^^^^^^^^^^^ NameError: name 'recommended' is not defined

Tags: python

```
# Создаем словарь с фильмами и их жанрами
movies = {
"Inception": "Sci-Fi",
"The Shawshank Redemption": "Drama",
"The Godfather": "Crime",
"Pulp Fiction": "Crime",
"The Dark Knight": "Action",
"Interstellar": "Sci-Fi",
"Fight Club": "Drama",
"Forrest Gump": "Drama",
"The Matrix": "Sci-Fi",
"Avengers: Endgame": "Action"
}

# Функция для рекомендации фильмов на основе выбранного жанра
def recommend_movies(genre):
recommended = [movie for movie, movie_genre in movies.items() if movie_genre == genre]
if recommended:
print("Рекомендуемые фильмы в жанре " + genre + ":")
for movie in recommended:
print(movie)
else:
print("К сожалению, в нашем списке нет фильмов в жанре " + genre)
```

Comment: Чуть больше кода и информации, пожалуйста. Что за проект, какие цели, в каком месте ошибка? Если есть, то ссылку на git.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Задание
Создайте словарь с популярными фильмами и их жанрами.
Напишите программу для рекомендаций фильмов по определенным критериям.

Comment: программа не работает

Answer (score 1):

У вас в определении функции `recommend_movies()` неправильные отступы.
Правильный код выглядит так:

```
# Функция для рекомендации фильмов на основе выбранного жанра
def recommend_movies(genre):
    recommended = [movie for movie, movie_genre in movies.items() if movie_genre == genre]
    if recommended:
        print("Рекомендуемые фильмы в жанре " + genre + ":")
        for movie in recommended:
            print(movie)
    else:
        print("К сожалению, в нашем списке нет фильмов в жанре " + genre)
```

Comment: Так дело было в отступах? Разве тогда не была бы ошибка IndentationError?

Comment: В программе у меня так, но почему то, сюда этот код не пропускает. Пишет чтобы я все отформатировала.

Comment: @ΝNL993 - *«Так дело было в отступах?»* Да. Я не знаю, какие отступы были действительно в оригинальном коде, но мной исправленный код работает так, как было нужно.

Comment: спасибо, действительно один съехал. Ошибка ушла

Comment: Я понял в чём была ошибка. Переменная `recommended` была объявлена в scope-е `recommend_movies`, и на этом функция закончилась, дальше была работа только с глобальным скоупом, поэтому и вылезала такая ошибка.

Comment: @Юлия, не стоит. Вы можете принять мой ответ (клик на галочку возле него), когда он был полезным дла вас. См. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @ΝNL993, вы очень вероятно прав.

Comment: @Юлия, насчет вставки кода есть справка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code